# How To Get The Selected Shipping/Delivery Method In Checkout Ui Extensions

Tags: shopify, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I have a text field checkout ui extension that I'm looking to modify. I'm wondering how to utilize the [deliveryGroups API](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/checkout-ui-extensions/unstable/apis/standardapi#properties-propertydetail-deliverygroups) to get the selected shipping method. This is my current code for my extension. Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

```
import {
  useExtensionApi,
  render,
  TextField,
  useApplyAttributeChange,
} from '@shopify/checkout-ui-extensions-react';

render("Checkout::ShippingMethods::RenderAfter", () => <App />);

function App() {
  const { extensionPoint } = useExtensionApi();
  const [shippingAccountInfo, setShippingAccountInfo] = useState('');

  const handleShippingChange = (val) => {
    setShippingAccountInfo(val)
  }

  const applyAttributeChange = useApplyAttributeChange();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (shippingAccountInfo) {
      // Update the checkout line item with the VAT number attribute
      async function updateShippingAttribute() {
        let res = await applyAttributeChange({
          type: 'updateAttribute',
          key: 'shipping_info',
          value: shippingAccountInfo,
        });
      }

      updateShippingAttribute()
    }
  }, [shippingAccountInfo, applyAttributeChange]);


  return (
    <>
      <TextField
        label="Shipping Account Info: (Enter your carrier and account number)"
        name="shipping_account_info"
        value={shippingAccountInfo}
        onChange={(str) => handleShippingChange(str)}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```